# Large data in Cassandra renders cluster unresponsive

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.2

I have created a table in Cassandra 2.2.0 on AWS with a simple structure:

```
CREATE TABLE data_cache (
    cache_id text,
    time timeuuid,
    request_json_data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (cache_id, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 3600
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

I have 2 data center on AWS - eu and us-east.

The issue that i am experiencing is the table fills up to rapidly to the point that no more disk space is on the system. It is also problematic to truncate the table as the READ becomes unresponsible in CQLSH.

As you can see - I changed the default TTL to be 3600sec (or 1 hr) and the GC grace seconds to be shorter than the default 10 days.

Currently the Data is now 101GB per cluster and the system become unresponsive.
If i try a simple `select count(*) from data_cache` it sends me a connection time out - after 3 tries the cluster itself is lost. the Error log states a java out of memory.

What should i do different? what am I doing wrong?

Currently the TTL is there so that data doesnt destroy the server until we know how long we will use the cache for hence why its only set to 1hr - but if we deem that the cache should be built for 1 day - we will scale the capacity accordingly but we will also need to read from it and due to the crash we are unable to do so.

Comment: what instance type and storage are you using?

Comment: Yeah, `SELECT COUNT(*)` in Cassandra (or any distributed database) is *never* simple.  Avoid unbound or multi-key queries at all costs.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli m3.large. 4 servers in each zone. I have 2 DC.

Answer (score 4):

What you are experiencing has to be expected. Cassandra is good at retrieving one particular record, but not at retrieving billions of rows at once. Indeed, your simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_cache` is reading all your dataset under the hood. Due to the nature of Cassandra, [counting is hard](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/counting-keys-in-cassandra).

If you query by BOTH `cache_id` and `time` everything is fine, but if you don't then it's a call for trouble, especially if you don't have idea on how wide your rows are.

Beware that TTL generate tombstones, which will hit you sooner or later. The TTL thing doesn't guarantee that your free space will be collected, even if you lower the grace period. Indeed, with default params, SizeTieredCompactionStrategy takes 4 SSTables of around equal size, but if you don't have such equal tables, then compaction does, well, nothing. And with in the worst case, SizeTieredCompactionStrategy requires **the free space on your disk to be at least the size of the biggest CF being compacted**.

It seems to me you are trying to use Cassandra as a cache, but you are currently using it like a queue. I would rethink about the data model. If you come here with a better specification of what you want to achieve maybe we can help you.

Comment: Initially - the model was cache_id, request_data. However the disk filed up overtime too easily and started to crash the system. Then i remodel it over time so that I can attempt to flush the data over time and have a last time stamp that it went inside the table. However after reading your comments - perhaps it was a bad idea.

Comment: You have answered why the select i made renders the node unresponsive, however you didn't answer as to why the disk fills up so fast despite a TTL. Shouldn't the TTL ensure me that disk space is conserved if data is being deleted and compaction is being passed by to remove the tombstone?

Answer (score 1):

I think your first issue is related to compaction and more precisely to the ratio between write throughput and compaction. In the cassandra.yaml file there is a field `compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec`. If its value is lower than your write load Cassandra won't be able to clear space and it will end up with no dsik space and node crashing.

I am wondering whether your data is correctly spread among your cluster or not. I see here that you use a PARTITION_KEY `cache_id` and a CLUSTERING_KEY `time`. It means that any insert with the same `cache_id` goes to the same node. So if you got too few `cache_id` or too much `time` in the same `cache_id` the work load would not be equally distributed and there is a risk of unresponsive nodes. The limits you must keep in mind are no more than 100 000 rows per partition and no more than 100 Mb per partition.

Comment: I didnt know about the 100k / 100Mb limit. I know about token size and its relative to the number of nodes you have but I always though Cassandra can handle a large amount of data, or was that under the assumption of the amount of servers you had attached to it?

Comment: These are not hard limits. They exist for performance reasons. They are (good) rules of thumb of data modeling.

Comment: @azngunit81 Cassandra can handle large amount of partitions. But it does not handle too large partition (over 100 000 record or 100 Mb) very well. Still you can split a partition into several partitions by adding a partition key. For instance you can have one partition by `cache_id` and `day` : `((cache_id, day), time)`

Comment: @azngunit81 Did you try to increase `compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec` to free disk space faster ?

Comment: Trying to determine the write load as you mentioned in order to determine by how much i can increase by